# Acumatica Automation Steps

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, acumatica

I have created Report and added it to the Reports drop-down on the Customized Screen like this from Automation Steps:

[image: Reports drop-down]

Now the question is **how can I add Automation Step to the Customization Project** so that the user won't have to create Automation Step for this by itself.
I have not found any solution for this in the Acumatica Documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.   Automation steps can't be added to a customization project.

There are two ways you can do it

1) Add a post installation step/method to your customization to add the records to the database.   I don't recommend this method though as there is a lot that has to be taken into account.     Take a look in the help wiki for the "OnPublished" event.

2) Use the "Automation Definitions" screen to create an XML definition including your custom steps.    From here you can download the XML of the customized steps.      on deployment, load the automation definition and populate the values then "Activate" the definition which will create the steps.

There is a decent blog article here that outlines the steps for that:
http://blog.acumatica.com.sg/2013/06/automation-steps-and-definitions.html

I've also played around w/ combining #1 and #2 where my customization publishes the automation definition via SQL then you simply need to go in and activate it.

Comment: I knew those two ways, I was thinking if there is something besides this and as it came up there isn't. I think it will be very good for developers if Acumatica dev team develop some method to include this into customization without post installation step. Thanks.

Comment: I agree.   I've been playing around with doing some of these in the OnPublished event to automate adding the definitions and activating them right from there.   As long as the customization matches the Acumatica version it should be good.    In fact I've been looking at doing that for a lot of items like this that you can't handle directly from the customization packages